# change data source properties in ibm websphere

Tags: websphere, datasource

I would like to update data source properties in IBM Websphere 8.5.5.0 using a script. Generally these properties are updated manually using admin console, but I would like to do it automatically. For this I need to know the ***.properties*** or ***.xml*** file or ****.**** in which data source configurations are stored.
Can anyone help me with this please.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know how to update the configurations in the admin console, you could use the built-in command assistance to see what underlying wsadmin command was run by the update.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0812_rhodes/0812_rhodes.html

> Generate a command using the console The first method is the most
>   basic use of command assistance. You launch the administrative
>   console, perform an action, and access the command assistance panel,
>   which displays the wsadmin command for that action.

Answer (score 0):

DataSource configuration is stored in an xml file, but should not be edited directly by users.

If you want to use a script, use wsadmin to modify the properties you need.

See this doc for full information on modifying datasource properties using wsadmin:
[Configuring new data source custom properties using wsadmin](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_configcustom.html)